# BSOD after cloning data hard drive Windows Vista Ultimate

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, bsod, data-transfer, disk-cloning

I have an issue with my current system not running properly after I clone my data drive to another, bigger hard drive. I have tried Acronis TruImage as well as a couple of other programs that I cannot remember at the moment.

When I clone the drives, it takes ~3.5 hours to complete since it is almost a full TB of data. After the cloning process is complete, i disconnect the old drive and connect the new drive to the same SATA port that the old drive was connected to, and boot. It will boot into Vista, then after about 5-10 mins, I get a blue screen with A "STOP 0x0000001E error, followed by 0x0000000000000000 in the rest of the data slots.

I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Weird, I don't know but some thing i might try and check out. Check first in the device manager, for anything. Then do the hidden devices tweak, and cleanup extra ghosted items there first. Test with "active" virus scanners turned off temporarily. Run Autoruns, and check in the "paths" for missing items. If your overclocked reduce the overclock for a bit, specially any memory tweaks. Check and reset the paging file setup. Run the task manager as soon as you get going, to monitor what is occuring. Disable some of the startup items to test, check driver things again.

Comment: In the device manager, I have a Sxuptp driver error. Every time i try to update it, it will blue screen. My assumption is that might be causing my issue, but I dont really have any conclusive evidence leading to it.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into safe mode and see if the BSOD happens. If it doesn't, try rebooting and see what happens. I have had the same issue at times and it seems to have always been some glitch with the video driver. Booting into safe mode then rebooting seems to always fix the issue.

Comment: I booted into Safe Mode and Safe Mode with networking, and it still gives the same result. Luckily I don't have to work tomorrow so I will have time to mess around with the system.

Comment: Sorry to hear you still have a problem. Next thing I would try is reinstall the OS in place so you don't lose your programs and data.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking about doing. But I might try one more cloning tool before i do that. Since Ive been doing hot clones, ill try one that runs without accessing the OS and data drive.